# .AsNoTracking() not working entity framework core 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework with this configuration on the Startup:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(
                   Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                     //b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)
                     b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ThreeTasty.Infrastructure")
           )
           .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            );
```

and in my Entity framework query I am trying to get the entity without tracking:

```
 query = query.Include(x => x.OrderProducts.Where(x => x.Active == true))
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductImages).AsNoTracking()

                        //order product with images
                        .Include(x => x.OrderProducts.Where(x => x.Active == true))
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductVendors)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.VendorProductSizeUnit).AsNoTracking();
```

Even after doing the `.AsNoTracking()` on the last entity `VendorProductSizeUnit` in the `.ThenInclude()` I get the following error while updating entity in a separate table:

The instance of entity type 'VendorProductSizeUnit' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Comment: `AsNoTracking` is just for that query and should be working. The exception you are getting is from `Update` procedure, and apparently there are different entity instances with the same key inside the input graph. If the input is directly coming from the shown query, try using `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` in place of `AsNoTracking()` - see [No-tracking queries with identity resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#no-tracking-queries-with-identity-resolution).

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for mentioning that this was new for me, do you think I should set `.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution)` in my Db Context setup? so every get query is with notracking IdentityResolution and EF can itself do the updates based of the Id?